# Postgresql slave for Mysql Master. Possible?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, replication, database-replication

I need to make some tests for a potential migration from Mysql to PostgreSql.
It will be easier to test if it is possible to use Postgre as slave for my MySQL master.

Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

No.

You can build something yourself using triggers and an external process to send data over, but it's fairly difficult since mysql has a rather limited support for triggers.

For your scenario you're likely to be better off doing periodic dumps of the data over. The best way is often to migrate the schema manually, and then send your data over as CSV. The "mysqldump --compatible" usually doesn't work well enough.

Comment: If migrating the schema manually is an option, this basically becomes the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417386/import-mysql-dump-to-postgresql-database. And while "--compatible" is indeed insufficient, some of the solutions they mention there, such as using pgloader, are probably better than just sending a CSV.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. Sort of. Maybe.

One solution that supposedly supports MySQL -> PostgreSQL migration is Continuent's open-source [Tungsten Replicator](https://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/).

You can see some instructions on how to implement this "Heterogeneous Replication" [here](https://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/wiki/TRCHeterogeneousReplication#MySQL_to_PostgreSQL_and_Oracle_Replication) (although the method they suggest, using tungsten-installer, is deprecated and you might be better off using tpm like [so](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tungsten-replicator-discuss/PKUOjK36R7s)).

Thing is, while there are [plenty](https://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/wiki/FAQ#Can_you_replicate_from_one_SQL_platform_to_another?_Example:_Rep) [of](http://2ndquadrant.com/media/pdfs/talks/char11/Real-time%20replication%20from%20MySQL%20to%20PostgreSQL%20using%20open%20source%20Tungsten.pdf) [resources](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tungsten) indicating Tungsten really did use to support this, officially it seems [they no longer do](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tungsten-replicator-discuss/cwnkm_AaBdo). This means that if you try to use the most recent Tungsten Replicator version (3.*), you'll quickly find that some files needed for Postgres are missing.

If, on the other hand, you try to download an older version, say 2.2.1, none of those errors appear, and all the files seem to be present, which leaves some room for optimism.

Personally, I must admit I haven't been able to get 2.2.1 to work either, but this probably has more to do with my lack of experience using Tungsten Replicator in general, and not with Postgres support. Also, in my case the real-time element wasn't as important, so we just ended up going with a cron job running [pgloader](http://pgloader.io/howto/pgloader.1.html).

So, if real-time replication from MySQL to Postgres is something you must have, I'd recommend at least trying out Tungsten Replicator before you start implementing a solution of your own. However, if real-time isn't an absolute requirement, there are probably simpler ways.

(Also, you might want to have a look at [SymmetricDS](http://www.symmetricds.org/) which claims to do something similar, though I haven't personally looked into it.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, master-slave replication is only possible between same databases.

You could configure MySQL using the [PostgreSQL-SQL-mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_postgresql) and you could also make a dump ready to import in Postgresql by using [--compatible](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible) in mysqldump.

Answer (score 0):

SymmetricDS does support MySQL to Postgres replication.   There is an open source version available as well as a professional version which provides a web based interface.