# How to export a mySql database to a embedded database (for example H2)?

Tags: mysql, database, export, h2

We have been working on a project. In the beginning we had some database issues, so we used a mySQL-server database to work around this.

Now we really should get back to an embedded database, access is out of the question (has to be cross-platform)

Our mentor suggested using an H2 embedded database, but we our sql-dump is getting syntax errors if we try to run it in the console of H2.

Any thoughts? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of syntax errors did you get? If possible, I would try to fix those (making the SQL script database independent).

Comment: @Tomas even with SQLite you will get syntax errors.

Answer (score 3):

To generate suitable for H2 SQL script on unix system you may try the following:

```
mysqldump -u root -c --p --skip-opt db_name | sed -e "/^--/d" -e 's/`//g' -e 's/bigint(20)/numeric(20)/g' -e 's/double\(([^(]*)\)/double/' -e 's/int(11)/integer/g' -e '/^\/\*.*\*\//d' -e '/^LOCK TABLES/d' -e '/^\/\*/,/\*\//c\;' -e '/^CREATE TABLE/,/);/{/^  KEY/d; /^  PRIMARY KEY/ s/,$//}' > db.sql
```

Currently it is not supporting conversion of all mysql specific statements, feel free to edit and add additional conversions.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL script generated by MySQL is made to run against MySQL. It contains options and features that other databases don't support.

As described in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417386/import-mysql-dump-to-postgresql-database), you could try creating the dump using the [compatibility option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible). But you may still need to fix problems manually.