# Python script to import mysql to postgresql

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql

With reference to [Import MySQL dump to PostgreSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417386/import-mysql-dump-to-postgresql-database).
An unknown developer has offered there to use the following script to import MySQL database to PostgreSQL

```
import MySQLdb
#from magic import Connect #Private mysql connect information - I COMMENTED THIS LINE to use direct connection
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="USER", # your username
                      passwd="PASS", # your password
                      db="w3i") # name of the data base
import psycopg2

dbx=Connect()
DB=psycopg2.connect("dbname='w3i'")
DC=DB.cursor()

mysql='''show tables from w3i'''
dbx.execute(mysql); ts=dbx.fetchall(); tables=[]
for table in ts: tables.append(table[0])
for table in tables:
    mysql='''describe w3i.%s'''%(table)
    dbx.execute(mysql); rows=dbx.fetchall()
    psql='drop table %s'%(table)
    DC.execute(psql); DB.commit()

    psql='create table %s ('%(table)
    for row in rows:
        name=row[0]; type=row[1]
        if 'int' in type: type='int8'
        if 'blob' in type: type='bytea'
        if 'datetime' in type: type='timestamptz'
        psql+='%s %s,'%(name,type)
    psql=psql.strip(',')+')'
    print psql
    try: DC.execute(psql); DB.commit()
    except: pass

    msql='''select * from w3i.%s'''%(table)
    dbx.execute(msql); rows=dbx.fetchall()
    n=len(rows); print n; t=n
    if n==0: continue #skip if no data

    cols=len(rows[0])
    for row in rows:
        ps=', '.join(['%s']*cols)
        psql='''insert into %s values(%s)'''%(table, ps)
        DC.execute(psql,(row))
        n=n-1
        if n%1000==1: DB.commit(); print n,t,t-n
    DB.commit()
```

As you can see - I changed line 2 to direct connection with MySQL

But now I have the following error

```
python postgres.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "postgres.py", line 9, in <module>
    dbx=Connect()
NameError: name 'Connect' is not defined
```

Thanks in advance for a hint how to solve it !

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : I forgot the cursor ...

EDIT2 : original script did not correctly process fields of TINYTEXT, MEDIUMTEXT or LONGTEXT type => added a conversion to PostgreSQL `TEXT` type

EDIT3 : the original script did not process ENUM fields, choked on non 7 bits characters, and had a wrong error management

You commented out line 2 where `Connect` was defined, but you left line 9 where `Connect()` is used untouched, so the error.

As you now explicitely connect to MySQL, you should replace `dbx = Connect()` with :

```
dbx = db.cursor()
```

It should now give (with the conversion of `TEXT` types line 28):

```
import MySQLdb
#from magic import Connect #Private mysql connect information - I COMMENTED THIS LINE to use direct connection
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="USER", # your username
                      passwd="PASS", # your password
                      db="w3i") # name of the data base
import psycopg2

# set client_encoding if different that PostgreSQL database default
encoding = 'Latin1'

dbx=db.cursor()
DB=psycopg2.connect("dbname='w3i'")
DC=DB.cursor()
DC.execute("set client_encoding = " + encoding)

mysql='''show tables from w3i'''
dbx.execute(mysql); ts=dbx.fetchall(); tables=[]
for table in ts: tables.append(table[0])
for table in tables:
    mysql='''describe w3i.%s'''%(table)
    dbx.execute(mysql); rows=dbx.fetchall()
    psql='drop table %s'%(table)
    DC.execute(psql); DB.commit()

    psql='create table %s ('%(table)
    for row in rows:
        name=row[0]; type=row[1]
        if 'int' in type: type='int8'
        if 'blob' in type: type='bytea'
        if 'datetime' in type: type='timestamptz'
        if 'text' in type: type='text'
        if 'enum' in type:
            type = 'varchar'
            print ("warning : conversion of enum to varchar %s(%s)" % (table, name))
        psql+='%s %s,'%(name,type)
    psql=psql.strip(',')+')'
    print psql
    try: DC.execute(psql); DB.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        DB.rollback()
```

Above script `convert` enum to `VARCHAR`. If you have only one enum type you can try to create it PostgreSQL side :

```
DC.execute("DROP TYPE IF EXISTS enumtyp CASCADE")
DC.execute("CREATE TYPE enumtyp AS ENUM( ... )"
```

where `enumtyp` is the name of the type and  `...` is the list of (textual) values (don't forget to add an empty value if the field can be empty in MySQL)

Then you replace `enum` with `enumtyp` by replacing line `type = 'varchar'` with :

```
        if 'enum' in type:
            type = 'enumtyp'
```

Comment: You way seems to be closer to a solution, but using #dbx=Connect() I have error
   File "postgres.py", line 14, in <module>
    db.execute(mysql); ts=db.fetchall(); tables=[]
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'execute'
...may be any other ideas ?

Comment: @Serge : Looks like I forgot the cursor ... should work better now :-)

Comment: Yes :) we go closer...now it actually tries to do something but now I see error on   File "postgres.py", line 20, in <module>
    DC.execute(psql); DB.commit()
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: table "categories" does not exist 
What is could be ?

Comment: @Serge : This one I know ! As you are migrating tables from MySQL to PostgreSQL, at beginning they do not exist. You must replace line 19 `psql='drop table %s'%(table)` with `psql='drop table if exists %s'%(table)`

Comment: ...and it works ! but till next error...now it looks like 
create table categories (id int8,name varchar(255),alternates mediumtext)
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "postgres.py", line 20, in <module>
    DC.execute(psql); DB.commit()
psycopg2.InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
...I regret we can't catch the author of this script to ask him what he meant writing this code ! ...from one point of view it could be a good instrument of import MySQL>PostgreSQL - but now I've no any idea what else to try...

Comment: @Serge : Script author never used `MEDIUMTEXT` fields (I never used `TEXT` either under PostgreSQL). I added a line for converting them to `TEXT` type. Good luck ... two *Serge* working together cannot fail :-)

Comment: I can't believe :)) we have reached line 44 in the code. First of all, SERGE :) I've missed line 28 `if 'text' in type: type='text'` - but when I added the one - an about last error has arised as `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "post.py", line 44, in <module>
    DC.execute(psql,(row))
psycopg2.InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`

Comment: This error is due to a previous one. IMHO the cause is the conversion of MEDIUMTEXT to TEXT.

Comment: I'm just afraid this script is bad :( that's a pity because idea was very good...but I'm not Python-master to correct the code in a right way. I've noted that with all your correctations - the import was good while it was importing two first but EMPTY tables, but when third table with real data "happenned" - again same issue  `File "post.py", line 46, in <module>
    DC.execute(psql,(row))
psycopg2.InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`
Script is bad :( that's true...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65307/discussion-between-serge-ballesta-and-serge).

Comment: Sorry I lost the chat and cannot connect back. I will propose a solution in a while ...

Answer (score 0):

as reported in the answer you cite:

```
from magic import Connect #Private mysql connect information
```

`Connect()` is (I assume) a method feeding parameters to connect to a specific db.

You thus have either to implement on your own this `magic` module, with references to your specific parameters, or to specify which connection you want to setup, namely `MySQLdb.connect(...)` or `psycopg2.connect(...)`

Comment: You're right, I've installed python-magic for magic - but I have no any idea or hint how to create Connect under python-magic...this is why I try to use a direct MySql connection

Comment: I don't think this was the case. python-magic is for something else. Make your own module and wrap the connection to the database into a method Connect()

Comment: I wish I could if I could know :) how to write a Python module...by the way - when I was trying without python-magic - it even did not start anything...so python-magic definitely has a matter here. Another question how to write this "Connect" so that magic could import the one