# Export MySQL database and import it to PostgreSQL database

Tags: php, python, mysql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to export **MySQL** database and import it to **PostgreSQL** database.

## I've tried

using this [mysql-postgresql-converter](https://github.com/lanyrd/mysql-postgresql-converter) python script

---

## I have a PHP script

```
if (!ini_get('date.timezone')) {
    ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/New_York');
}


//Configuration
$db          = 'local';
$username    = 'root';
$hostname    = '127.0.0.1';
$password    = '';
$date        = date('Y-m-d');
$export_type = 'mysql'; // option : mysql | psql
$file_name   = $date.'-portal';
$file_path   = $file_name;

if($export_type == 'mysql'){
    // MySQL Export
    $cmd = 'mysqldump --compatible=postgresql --default-character-set=utf8 -r '.$db.'.mysql -u root '.$db;
    echo $cmd. PHP_EOL;
    exec($cmd);
}

// Convert
$import = 'python db_converter.py '.$db.'.mysql '.$db.'.psql';
echo $import. PHP_EOL;
exec($import);

//Import to PostSQL
$import = 'psql  -U bheng  -d portal -f '.$db.'.psql';
echo $import. PHP_EOL;
exec($import);
```

---

## Result

I got 2 files created

1- local.mysql
2- local.psql

---

As soon as I run

```
psql  -U bheng  -d portal -f local.psql
```

I get

```
psql:local.psql:12: ERROR:  relation "caches" already exists
psql:local.psql:14: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:52: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:54: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:63: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:65: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:78: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:80: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:92: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:94: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:110: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:112: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:116: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:118: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:131: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:133: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:144: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:146: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:158: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:160: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:179: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:181: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:195: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:197: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:247: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:249: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:256: ERROR:  cannot cast type smallint to boolean
LINE 1: ...LT, ALTER COLUMN "sign_enable" TYPE boolean USING CAST("sign...
                                                             ^
psql:local.psql:257: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:258: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:263: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:264: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:265: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:266: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:267: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:268: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:269: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:270: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:271: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:272: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:273: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:274: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:275: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:276: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:277: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:278: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:279: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:280: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:281: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:282: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:283: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:284: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:285: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:286: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:287: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:288: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:289: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:290: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:291: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:292: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:293: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:294: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:local.psql:295: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

---

Any hints / suggestions on this will be much appreciated !

Comment: Maybe take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417386/import-mysql-dump-to-postgresql-database

Comment: Reconsider using that GitHub script as it mentions: *This script was designed for our specific database and column requirements*. So there might be some syntax/types in your database not handled in above script leading to Postgre errors.

Comment: Consider the long way of export/import csv files or using php/python to connect between both servers and running SQL DML and DDL statements.

Comment: Sure, thank-you for your advice. I'll look into those export/import csv files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pgloader.

```
sudo apt-get install pgloader
```

Using:

pgloader mysql://user:pass@host/database postgresql://user:pass@host/database

Example:

```
pgloader mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/mydbinmysql postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/mydbexportedonpgsql
```

Just create the new db to which you want to export to in postgres beforehand. In the example above mydbexportedonpgsql.