# Failed to migrate from Mysql 8 to postgres using pgloader

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration, pgloader

I'm trying to migrate from MySQL to PostgreSQL database.

Is there any way to migrate from MySQL to PostgreSQL without modifying the `my.cnf` file?

```sh
pgloader mysql://root:root_password@127.0.0.1/mysql_database postgresql://postgres_user:postgres_pass@127.0.0.1/postgres_database
```

I tried creating this:

```
create user 'pgloader'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'pass'
```

But when I try the migration, I always get this error:

```
Failed to connect to mysql at "localhost" (port 3306) as user "pgloader": Condition QMYND:MYSQL-UNSUPPORTED-AUTHENTICATION was signalled.
```

Answer (score 9):

As of April 2021, pgloader lacks support for the newer SHA2 authentication mode in MySQL v8. (It's a fair bit of work to upgrade.)

I ran into this issue 3 times over the last year.

#### 1st Approach

For the 1st client I was able to downgrade MySQL to [v5.6 following comments here.](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/782#issuecomment-501331182)

#### 2nd Approach

For the 2nd client with a small-ish database I hacked some shell scripts together.

1. SSH to grab `mysqldump` (definitely needed to play with the options.)
2. [Reformatting SQL syntax to postgres.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31351914/369727)
3. Then exec against postgres target.

#### 3rd Approach

My 3rd client had much more data, 4-5TB in hundreds of tables.

This time I found [NMIG, a Node-based configurable data migration tool.](https://github.com/AnatolyUss/nmig) After a bit of tuning & config, it seems to be working pretty well.

**I'd definitely reach for NMIG in the future.**

Comment: What a bizarre world, where someone wrote a database migration tool in Node and somehow that tool is actually one of the best options available.